# React native android Error: org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorException: Could not create CompressorInputStream

Tags: android, react-native, tar

I am using react-native-archiver to extract tar file.

```
   const targetPath = ExternalDirectoryPath;
   RNArchiver.untar(ExternalDirectoryPath + '/content.tar', targetPath)
     .then(path => {
       console.log(`untar completed at ${path}`)
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
     })
```

I have this error on android :

`Error: org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorException: Could not create CompressorInputStream.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem by changing this line of code in RNArchiverModule.java inside node modules -> react-native-archiver ->android

From :

```
Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(ArchiveFormat.TAR, CompressionType.GZIP);
```

To :

```
 Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(ArchiveFormat.TAR);
```

It was extracting tar.gz not tar.

But still the library never support ios and I need to find a solution for that?